# G++ 4.9 - function at module scope not being called?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am using a module-level function call to register a factory function with a  registry class:

```
static Controller * ctor( Device * device, const char * ) { return new NullController(device); }
static int s_id = DeviceRegistry::RegisterControllerClass( "null", ctor );

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

NullController::NullController( Device * device )
: Controller( device, "null", s_id )
{
}
```

where eg::DEV::DeviceRegistry::RegisterControllerClass() is a free function in the namespaces eg and DEV. This works well under Visual Studio, but the code does not appear to be called when running on GCC/Linux - if I breakpoint the RegisterControllerClass(), it does not get invoked. Just in case the compiler was optimizing out the s_id field, I used it to construct the base class. So I'm sure it's not that. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You must ensure that translation unit is linked in. One way is to call a function in it from `main`.

Comment: What is module scope?

Comment: Within the translation unit (ie the cpp file + included headers). Had they not been marked 'static' I would have said 'global'.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @NathanOliver working on it...

Comment: Interestingly, I cannot. A simple example works as I expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linker was trying to be too clever and removing code that it thought was not called, but would be invoked indirectly.

Adding command line options in the Netbeans linker options dialog around the library

-Wl,--whole-archive
  lib
  -Wl,--no-whole-archive
  ...

solves the problem. Yuk.

Comment: W1? Are you kidding? -Wl.

Comment: @KonstantinVladimirov lol, fun with fonts (remembers coding rule about never using 'l' as a variable)